# How to select multiple rows of the same user that satisfies some condition in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

A have the following data

```
id user_id visited_country
1  12      Spain 
2  12      France
3  14      England
4  14      France
5  16      Canada
6  14      Spain
```

I want to select all users who have visited both **Spain** and **France**. How can I do that in MySQL?

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING COUNT DISTINCT etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should suffice:

```
select user_Id
from t
where visited_country in ('Spain','France')
group by User_Id
having Count(distinct visited_country) = 2;
```

Comment: Thank you, what if I want to exclude those who have visited "England"?

Comment: @Aman That was not the question you asked, don't move the goal posts, ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks, I will do post as a new question. I revert it back to the original

Answer (score 0):

@Aman: If you are trying to exclude England then it would be

```
select distinct user_Id
from table
where visited_country in ('Spain','France')
and not exists
(Select distinct user_id
 From table where visited_country in ('England'))
group by User_Id
having Count(distinct visited_country)> = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it didn't work as expected

Comment: Hi @Aman:can you try now..I have edited the query

Comment: Sorry, It didn't workout again. I found a simple solution to this, here is the link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72118706/7322834