# How to filter users that have multiple rows where row1="value1" and row2="condition2", ... in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

A have the following data

```
id user_id visited_country
1  12      Spain 
2  12      France
3  14      England
4  14      France
5  16      Canada
6  14      Spain 
7  16      Mexico
```

I want to select all users who have visited both **Spain** and **France**, **excluding** those who have visited **England**. How can I do that in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One aggregation approach might be:

```sql
SELECT user_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(visited_country = 'Spain') > 0 AND
       SUM(visited_country = 'France') > 0 AND
       SUM(visited_country = 'England') = 0;
```

Comment: Works pretty well and also very clean code. Thanks.